# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initTag' : how can I solve this?

Tags: eyed3

I had an error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
so I found it can be solved with running initTag.
but as I ran initTag, I got an error :
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initTag'.
and there was no tag in the MP3 files.
Below are the code :

```
for i in range(len(namelist)):
        path = "%s.mp3" % namelist[i]
        tag = eyed3.load(path1)
        tag.initTag()
        tag.tag.artist = artistlist[i]
        tag.tag.album = albumlist[i]
        tag.tag.save()
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you aware that `.initTag()` is _removing any existing tag if one exists_?

Comment: Are you aware that you assign to `path` and use `path1`?